# What is the best approach to handle Bluetooth streams in background using a repository pattern?

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, rx-java, rx-android

I need a handler for Bluetooth connection with a frequency of 1Hz  and using like a Repository  pattern, save data in SQliteDB and display info on several views of the App.

My current choice is RxBluetooth + service, but I'm looking for other straight forward alternatives but without compromising performance. I saw there are new stuffs on Android Jetpack, maybe RxBus, or other RxJava features, etc.

I just want simplest but efficient approach to face this.

I read you, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found that a combination of RxBluetooth+Service to keep an event-based consistent reception, LiveData+ViewModel to keep the UI state and Room for persistence model is perfect for my requirements.